# Identify different field types in a fillable PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I am new to C# and PDFsharp so I'm not sure what is the best way to check different field types. Right now I am using the following code to replace the value in text fields, but this is because I know that the field is a checkbox.

But if I am to loop through the fields obtained from the PDF, how do I check if the field is a checkbox or a text field or something else entirely?

```
PdfCheckBoxField currentField = (PdfCheckBoxField)(form["CheckBox2"]);
currentField.Checked = true;
```

How do I check the field type if, suppose, I loop through all the fields like so:

```
for (int i=0; i<form.Count; i++)
{
   field = form.Names[i];
}
```

I didn't find a lot of info in the PDFsharp site on this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know any pdfsharp details but if you cast fields to use their special type, you can obviously start by testing their type using `typeof`.

Comment: @mkl Post your comment as an answer. This is not a PDFsharp problem, but a C# noob question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most natural approach to determine which kind of form field you get for `form["CheckBox2"]` and in particular to which specific form field class you can cast it, is to simply determine the type of that object. This can either be done by testing for type compatibility using the [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) keyword or by testing for type identity using [`typeof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof) and [`GetType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var currentField = form["CheckBox2"];
if (currentField is PdfCheckBoxField)
{
    // the type of currentField is compatible with PdfCheckBoxField
    PdfCheckBoxField currentCheckBox = (PdfCheckBoxField)currentField;
    ...
}
```

or

```
var currentField = form["CheckBox2"];
if (currentField != null && currentField.GetType() == typeof(PdfCheckBoxField))
{
    // the type of currentField is PdfCheckBoxField
    PdfCheckBoxField currentCheckBox = (PdfCheckBoxField)currentField;
    ...
}
```

---

Starting with C# 7 the [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) keyword supports [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is):

```
var currentField = form["CheckBox2"];
if (currentField is PdfCheckBoxField currentCheckBox)
{
    // the type of currentField is compatible with PdfCheckBoxField
    // a PdfCheckBoxField variable currentCheckBox here already is declared and initialized with currentField
    ...
}
```